# Vuetify text-field won´t use computed property

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I would like a clearable v-text-field with a label to show a computed string property based on other another property (a boolean in this simplified example).

Initially it works, the correct default string value is shown.
If I invert the boolean with a button from outside the v-text-field component, the next correct string value is shown as expected.
But if I use the clear button in the v-text-field to invert the boolean, the v-text-field clears and uses the label in the input field when focus is lost, and therefore not using the expected string value.

Input:

```
<v-text-field  :value="text" label="Just a label" clearable  @click:clear="booleanModel = true;"></v-text-field>
```

Computed property:

```
text: function() {
      if(this.booleanModel) {
        return 'Its on'
      } else {
      return 'Default text';
      }
    }
```

As far as I can see via vue dev tools, the state in the v-text-field is the same either way.
How come, and how to avoid this?

Please refer to this example: https://codepen.io/fasterlars/pen/RwKrzXZ?editors=1010

Comment: What is the point of all this? How do you plan to get the value out of the textbox?

Comment: It´s because I have a textfield, which represents a daterange based on two date variables. If these are set, the text should be "date1 - date2", else the text should be "Daterange not set".
So the real value is the date variables, and the textbox is only representing those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be honest your use-case seems very strange but...

The problem is that `v-text-box` has some internal state (according to source code comments to make it work without the model) and on `clear` icon click it sets it to `null` **but** it does this in the `nextTick` - [source](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/master/packages/vuetify/src/components/VTextField/VTextField.ts#L254). This is little bit strange but they probably has some [reasons](https://github.com/bludnic/vuetify/commit/77a4e4c4f8256a7d0f224fd9321596563d6dde6c) to do so...

So if you don't want to really clear the content but instead set it to something else, do not use default "clearable" functionality and use `append` slot instead:

```html
<v-text-field :value="text" label="Just a label">
  <template v-slot:append>
    <v-icon @click="booleanModel = true">clear</v-icon>
  </template>
</v-text-field>
```

Comment: Thanks! Yea they probably have their reasons. But your solution worked perfectly!
Please see my answer to your previous comment for a explanation.

Answer (score -1):

When you click on the clear button, the value of `booleanModel` does not change.
You need to update the `@click:clear = "booleanModel = false;"`.

Also, add a `:key="booleanModel` in your text field, which will ensure that whenever the value of `booleanModel` changes it will re-render the `v-text-field` component again.

Comment: Thanks alot, it works on the codepen with the :key attribute, so I will accept your answer. My problem is that the text-field component crashes in my real code issue when doing this  - but I will create another more detailed question for that.

Comment: Sorry, @Michael Levý´s answer did solve my initial problem, so his answer will be accepted.